# AWS SAM CLI java8 runtime is not supported

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam

I'm trying to build a Lambda application using `AWS SAM CLI` command:

```
sam build --template C:/MyProject/template.yaml --build-dir C:/MyProject/.aws-sam/build
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Build Failed
>
> Error: 'java8' runtime is not supported

This is my `template.yaml`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  AWS Serverless Application
  Sample SAM Template for AWS Serverless Application
Globals:
  Function:
      Timeout: 20
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
          CodeUri: target/HelloWorld-1.0.jar
          Handler: helloworld.App::handleRequest
          Runtime: java8
          Environment: 
              Variables:
                  PARAM1: VALUE
          Events:
              HelloWorld:
                  Type: Api
                  Properties:
                      Path: /hello
                      Method: get
```

It's an example project made in `Intellij` using `AWS Toolkit` plugin, I have installed `SAM CLI` version `0.9.0` and `jdk1.8.0_191` (I've tried different versions but it didn't work), at the project's [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli) I can see that `java 8` is supported:

```
[ ] Supported AWS Lambda Runtimes
    [x] java8
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Got the same error.  Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Still no progress, for now I have to test everything in AWS without local testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `build` option doesn't support the `java8` runtime

When I run `sam build --help` the result is: [image] which implies that it only works for python

Comment: That's correct, Java 8 support for build is still under development: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/880

Comment: This is not true anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

Previously, I had given like below,

```
CodeUri: hello-world.jar
```

I have changed it to

```
CodeUri: ./hello-world
```

where hello-world is my java project's source directory.